# Android Studio Arctic Fox: Problem in Create new Project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-studio-arctic-fox

I have updated my android studio to Android Studio Arctic Fox but after creating a new project the Gradle configuration has totally changed, and the build Gradle has failed.
I have questions:
1-Do settings like ClassPath for Gradle have to be added manually?

```
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.1.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1)
```

2-this is my build.gradle file, what does apply false means?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.30' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This issue might be related to missed repository. Please check you fave added at least `google()` and `mavenCentral()` to `repositories` section in your root `build.gradle`.
2. From the gradle official docs (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl):

> If you have a multi-project build, you probably want to apply plugins
> to some or all of the subprojects in your build, but not to the root
> project. The default behavior of the plugins {} block is to
> immediately resolve and apply the plugins. But, you can use the apply
> false syntax to tell Gradle not to apply the plugin to the current
> project and then use the plugins {} block without the version in
> subprojects' build scripts: